# Apply changes to an element when an adjacent element is hovered using CSS

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to apply CSS when I `hover` an adjacent element. My CSS look like this:

```
.class1:hover + .class2 {}
```

This is supposed to be a menu. When I hover `.menuNormal`, `.mnuExtended` should be visible. This is my HTML/CSS:

```
<style>
.menuNormal {width:100px; height:100px; background-color:FFF}
.menuExtended {width:100px; height:100px; background-color:green; display:none;}
.menuNormal:hover + .menuExtended{display:block;}
</style>

<body>
<div class="menuNormal">
<p>hover to unfold extra menu</p>
</div>

<div class="menuExtended">
<p>here are some menu buttons</p>
</div>
</body>
```

I'm trying to change `.menuExtended` from `display:none` to `display:block` but it doesn't seem to work. Is there something wrong I am doing?

Comment: So what are you expecting here?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: i'm trying to define the menuExtended to change display:none to display:block so that i can see them but i don't know how to do that

Comment: @MeQube your code is doing that. check here http://jsfiddle.net/X5TZK/

Comment: @MeQube Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/bdNWf/

Comment: weard cuze it does not work in my project

Comment: @MeQube Are you sure this is not working? Sowmya and Mr.Alien jsFiddle works okay on every browser.

Comment: could otherwise somebody looke than on the project site? http://www.ijsselbijkers.nl/index.php

Comment: @MeQube Of course. Are top right buttons who have to work like that?

Comment: @MeQube It's working for me :S When I hover them, it shows a `<div>` with white background

Comment: @DaGLiMiOuX yes but in that div is a small text (asdfadsfasdfas) with a color:#000 but that does not show up

Comment: @MeQube Remove `+` from your class assignation and it will work ;)

Comment: @MeQube Try as shown in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `.menublokcontainer:hover + div.menuExtention` write like shown below

```
.menublokcontainer > div:hover .menuExtention {
width: 135px;
height: 121px;
display: block;
}
```

Comment: I didn't tried this, but if you remove the `+` using the same class `.menublokcontainer:hover div.menuExtention` assignation, it works. I didn't tried your example, but probably will work too ;)

Answer (score -1):

you can use jQuery to do this:

```
$('.menuNormal').hover(function(){
    $('.menuExtended').css({'display':'block'});
});
```

Comment: Do you really think it is required??

Comment: @cutoverRooster dnt mind. I jus said coz of the comments posted for the question